# Where can I play Phase 10 online?

Tags: online, phase-10

Is there an online site to play the card game [Phase 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_10) on?
A clone is fine, but I'd really like to avoid a download.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [clone of Phase 10 called Wizard Cards](http://www.wizardcards.com/phase-10.shtml) you could download and install.  Magmic games has released versions of Phase 10 for [Blackberry](http://www.bplay.com/item/Phase10) and [iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/app/phase-10/id302049354?mt=8) also.  There doesn't seem to be a version you can play in your browser online at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact match and you may have considered it already, but [Uno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_%28card_game%29) is a broadly similar game (and a fellow member of the '[shedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_games#Shedding_games)' family of card games) - it has a huge number of [theme packs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_%28card_game%29#Theme_packs) and [online versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_%28card_game%29#Video_games).

Answer (score 0):

https://apps.facebook.com/phasetenapp/?fb_source=bookmark_favorites&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=13_0 has an app of phase 10. It's pretty fun only con is you cant play it as many times as you want, you have to wait for your energy to refill.

Comment: The link to the Facebook game is not working anymore.

Answer (score -1):

phase 10 on facebook.Great game but you can't play very often you have to wait for energy to refill. You can view video for energy but you only get one. They are very stingy with their energy this is very disappointing

Answer (score -2):

There is a Phase 10 game on facebook but you have to wait for your energy to fill up.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page so other people can find it easier.